# Get latitude, longitude and values from GeoTIFF as an array

Tags: python, tiff, gdal, rasterio

I am able to get values from a tiff file as a numpy array using the script below. How can I get latitude and longitude also as a numpy array.

```
import rasterio
rstr=rasterio.open(mytif.tif) 
val=rstr.read(1)
```

Comment: You have to get the geotransform and build the array yourself - the geotransform contains the coordinates of the upper-left point and the pixel step value